# Aligning DOM Containers Equidistantly from Each Other and Outer Container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a `<ul>` container that is styled with a certain class.

Its pertinent styles are

```
.resipes_filter .resipes_filter-dish {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
dl, ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Inside it, we have `<li>` items which have the following styles:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
width: 90px;
height: 90px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 1px;
```

The thing currently looks like this.

[image]

What I would like to happen is for the inner containers to align themselves harmoniously and smartly. This would mean equidistantly from each other and with the same margin from both sides (left and right) of the outer container.

How could one go about doing this?

P.S. The project is rolling raw CSS, so things like SASS or LESS are not really an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a lot of excitement last year about Flexbox - and you've discovered one of the reasons why.

There is a reason why the primary, core change from Bootstrap3 to Bootstrap4 is moving from floats to flexbox. Floats was the old way to position items; flexbox (and CSSGrid) are the new way. Flexbox is dead *easy*.

From your question, you will be most interested in:

```
justify-content: space-evenly;  (or perhaps "space-around")
```

Flexbox requires two things:

1. A parent container *(e.g. DIV, section, aside, p, etc)*  On this, put `display:flex;` and `justify-content: space-around;`
2. One or more child elements *(e.g. div, p, img, etc)* On these, put: `flex:1`

Resources:

[Here is an excellent 20min video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc)

[Here is a great cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/)

Comment: Amazing :-) Thank you!